# Bind an ObservableCollection to a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, data-binding

I'm using `Entity Framework` as my database source and need to convert a `Linq` query "var" type to an ObservableCollection. I then need to bind the ObservableCollection to a ComboBox on WPF form; binding to ItemsSource, DisplayMemeberPath, SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue.

Here is Code:

```
using (PulseContext pc = new PulseContext())
{
    var maritalcodes =  from m in pc.CodeMaster
                        where m.Type == "16"
                        select new { m.Code, m.Description };

    prop.ClientData.Options = new ObservableCollection<object>(maritalcodes);
}
```

Problem is the `ComboBox` is showing this as "{ Code = ????, Description = ???? }" instead of bind to code for value and description for display. What do I have to do to get the ComboBox to bind to the individual elements?

Comment: You should mark the best answers to your questions as your accepted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` like this:

```
prop.ClientData.Options = new ObservableCollection<object>(maritalcodes);
prop.ClientData.Options.SelectedValuePath = "Code";
prop.ClientData.Options.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
```

Or you can set them in xaml like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=maritalcodes}"
          SelectedValuePath="Code"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=maritalcodes}"
      SelectedValuePath="Code"
      DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Code}"/>
```

I hope this will help.